# I want to display the background color when clicking on the button for particular div

Tags: javascript, angular

```
<div class="mat-list-item"  *ngIf="authService.isAdmin()" (click)="openModal('site-settings', site.siteID)">
        <span class="mat-list-item-content">{{ "Application.site_settings_label" | translate }}</span>
      </div>
```

in js

```
openModal() {
    
  }
```

Comment: for a start, `openModal` is called with two arguments, and your function doesn't have any parameters ... then of course, the function needs to actually do something, and you haven't really tried to explain what it is it should be doing

Comment: There is no button in your html that you posted. `<button>` would be a button, you have a div. You should really be using a button tough.

Comment: It'll be great if you could provide codesandbox link

Answer (score 0):

Use window.getComputedStyle() in order to get the background color, otherwise styles that are not in a style attribute or set by JS aren't detected.

I removed the other parameter of the function for this example.

```js
function openModal() {
  const div = document.getElementById('myId');
  alert(window.getComputedStyle(div).backgroundColor);
}
```

```css
#myId {
 background-color: #ff0000;
 }
```

```html
<div class="mat-list-item" id="myId"  *ngIf="authService.isAdmin()" onClick="openModal()">
        <span class="mat-list-item-content">{{ "Application.site_settings_label" | translate }}</span>
      </div>
```